# ajax calendar extender multiple popup buttons handling

Tags: popup, calendarextender

I would like to open the calender popup on both the onclick of the image button and on focus of the text box "txtstartdate". Please help.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" Enabled="false" CssClass="dateBoxWidth TPRValue" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StartDate", "{0:ddd MMM dd, yyyy}")%>'></asp:TextBox>

<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnStartDate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Common/Images/Calendar.GIF" CausesValidation="false" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" />

<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="StartDateCalendar" TargetControlID="txtStartDate" PopupButtonID="imgBtnStartDate" runat="server" Format="ddd MMM dd, yyyy" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="onStartDateChanged"></ajax:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" onFocus="javascript:document.getElementById('imgBtnStartDate').click();" runat="server" Enabled="false" CssClass="dateBoxWidth TPRValue" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StartDate", "{0:ddd MMM dd, yyyy}")%>'        ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnStartDate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Common/Images/Calendar.GIF" CausesValidation="false" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" />

<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="StartDateCalendar" TargetControlID="txtStartDate" PopupButtonID="imgBtnStartDate" runat="server" Format="ddd MMM dd, yyyy" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="onStartDateChanged"></ajax:CalendarExtender>
```

In the TextBox control add the event

```
onFocus="javascript:document.getElementById('imgBtnStartDate').click();"
```

Hope this solves...

If you're using jQuery is better this one:

```
onFocus="javascript:$('#imgBtnStartDate').click();"
```